# Fillo library usage in Groovy script

Tags: java, groovy, xlsx

I try to use `Fillo` Excel API in a `Groovy` script in SoapUI to get values from a xlsx file. I copied jar file to /bin/ext folder and tried to execute sample select code. I got error message:

> org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException:
>   startup failed: Script6.groovy: 1: unable to resolve class Fillo @
>   line 1, column 7. Fillo fillo=new Fillo(); ^
>   org.codehaus.groovy.syntax.SyntaxException: unable to resolve class
>   Fillo @ line 1, column 7. at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.addError(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:149)
>   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.resolveOrFail(ResolveVisitor.java:264)
>   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.resolveOrFail(ResolveVisitor.java:274)
>   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.transformVariableExpression(ResolveVisitor.java:944)
>   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.transform(ResolveVisitor.java:696)
>   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.transformDeclarationExpression(ResolveVisitor.java:1083)
>   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.transform(ResolveVisitor.java:700)
>   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeExpressionTransformer.visitExpressionStatement(ClassCodeExpressionTransformer.java:142)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following imports are needed:

```
import com.codoid.products.exception.FilloException;
import com.codoid.products.fillo.Connection;
import com.codoid.products.fillo.Fillo;
import com.codoid.products.fillo.Recordset;
```